# Etherscan verification bytecodes don't match

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, bytecode, contract-verification

Hi I'm trying to verify a token deployed at [0x87ab739464881af0011052d4ca0b0d657e8c3b48](https://etherscan.io/address/0x87ab739464881af0011052d4ca0b0d657e8c3b48) in tx [0xbaa8f3fe86a35d2e0b7ed16b24782743e7dfb1eb21cfbb12253d0a50ef2ff365](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbaa8f3fe86a35d2e0b7ed16b24782743e7dfb1eb21cfbb12253d0a50ef2ff365). (Mainnet)

I compiled and deployed it with remix, options:

- Compiler version:0.5.2+commit.1df8f40c.Emscripten.clang
- Optimization: not enabled.

The contract source code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Capped.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Pausable.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol";

contract MTB19 is ERC20Pausable, ERC20Burnable, ERC20Capped, ERC20Detailed {

    constructor(uint256 cap, address prefund, uint256 amount) public ERC20Capped(cap) ERC20Detailed("MikeTangoBravo19", "MTB19", 18) {
        mint(prefund, amount);
    }

}
```

The constructor abi-encoded params are:

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003bfe5fd1c4b11cc0000000000000000000000000000d60b471bd8c62dc4d2f04493413c6cb73b7ce4640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002cfe905a78b63800000

(The openzeppelin dependecy is the one published in github [commit: e287eab])

The bytecode generated by Remix and the Etherscan expected bytecode are equal but when I introduce the flattened code and all the data provided to etherscan verifier bytecodes are totally different. How can I do it so that, bytecodes are the same and it verifies my contract?

Comment: What's the compiler version for openzeppelin code? When you flaten the code, everything is compiled with the same version (0.5.2 in your case), which could yield a different binary.

Comment: The pragma solidity of the openzeppelin code is 0.5.0

Comment: With `^` or without `^`?

Comment: With ^, like: pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

Comment: Etherscan Helpdesk found the solution. It seems the flattened sol file I was using was not correctly generated.

Comment: Something you you could (and should) have found yourself. When you post this question here, readers assume that you've done your part of the deal carefully and thoroughly.